# Multiple view folders with Node.js / Express

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I have read several answers but it's unclear how to make Express work with multiple view folders.

Let's say the Express app contains independent parts, organized in subfolders :

```
app
  +partA
     +views
        index.html
  +partB
     +views
        index.html
```

Then we set each folder as view :

```
app.set('views', [__dirname + '/partA/views', __dirname + '/partB/views']);
```

But how to access `index.html` in the second folder ?

In routes.js :

```
res.sendFile('index.html');
```

will always send part A.

Also we can't use the relative path :

```
res.sendFile('/partB/views/index.html');
```

will trigger the error :

`Error : Failed to lookup view "/partB/views/index.html" in views directories "/partA/views" or "/partB/views"`

So how to make this work ? I know the usual approach is to make the parts as subfolders of the view folder, but that's not an option. I don't want to have duplicate folders for each part in `/views`, `/public`, `/lib`, etc.

Answer (score 0):

What do you want when call `res.sendFile('index.html')` - partA or partB? How does Express must make choice?

Try
 
 1. `res.sendFile('../../partB/views/index.html');`
 2. In middleware `app.set('views', '/partB')` on part B request
 3. `app.set('views', '/')` and specify full path each time `res.sendFile('/partB/views/index.html');`

Comment: setting views for each request seems like an overkill... if I set views to '/' doesn't that imply some security issue ? like being able to access server files

Comment: Common way is store templates inside `views` (or `templates`) folder. App don't send templates directly via `sendFile`, but use `res.render(template-name)`. So, remote users don't have any access to templates.